# Python, bottle, and now to debug

Tags: python, bottle

This is from the docs......

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Interactive mode
    run(host='localhost', port=8049, debug=True)
```

This is the error I get.  What did I miss?

```
Bottle server starting up (using WSGIRefServer(debug=True))...
Listening on http://localhost:8049/
Hit Ctrl-C to quit.
Shutdown...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/rtbopsConfig/rtbServers/rtbUwsgiBidderServer/uwsgiBidderServer.py", line 1239, in <module>
    run(host='localhost', port=8049, debug=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bottle-0.10.11-py2.7.egg/bottle.py", line 2426, in run
    server.run(app)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bottle-0.10.11-py2.7.egg/bottle.py", line 2123, in run
    srv = make_server(self.host, self.port, handler, **self.options)
TypeError: make_server() got an unexpected keyword argument 'debug'
```

Comment: what happens when you lose `debug=True`?

Comment: It works but I cant debug 500 errors rendering bottle unusable as a web framework

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `debug=` parameter to run is only available [since](https://github.com/defnull/bottle/commit/f1a216cec765c77f4c5e7b66bfdfce9494c6a51b) bottle version 0.11. Either update bottle (for example by simply [downloading the up-to-date version](https://raw.github.com/defnull/bottle/master/bottle.py), and placing it in the directory of your application), or remove `debug=True` by replacing

```
run(host='localhost', port=8049, debug=True)
```

with

```
run(host='localhost', port=8049)
```

Comment: Then how do you debug bottle?  pip and easy install are not updated.  10 is the stable version. Prior to 11 one can not debug?

Comment: Well, it depends on your error, but you can debug it like any other python program, with pdb and a close look at the source.

Answer (score 6):

For versions prior to 0.11, you can enable the debug mode by doing:

```
bottle.debug(True)
bottle.run(host='localhost', port=8049)
```

Comment: I am using .10, from 13.04 repo, this gave me the same error.